# Parallel tangents on a torus

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

> Let $0 < r < b$ and let $X$ be the point on the torus that is given by
>   $$X = i((b + r \cos \theta) \cos \phi)
> +j((b + r \cos \theta) \sin \phi) 
>  + k(r \sin \theta)$$
>
> Show that the vectors $$\frac{\partial X}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial X}{\partial \phi} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial X}{\partial r}$$ are parallel.

To do this, I found ∂X/∂θ, ∂X/∂ψ and ∂X/∂r by differentiating with respect to the given variables,then found the cross product of ∂X/∂θ × ∂X/∂ψ. But then when I found the dot product of ∂X/∂θ × ∂X/∂ψ and ∂X/∂r it came out to be -r(b + r cos θ) which is not 1.

I'm just wondering if I've used the wrong method at any point or missed something obvious? thanks

Comment: To show two vectors are parallel you must check their cross product vanishes.

Comment: To expand on Aretino's comment: the dot product being $0$ means the vectors are perpendicular, not parallel. It is the cross product that is $0$ when they are parallel.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed this, but it worked :)